# How to bind an Image control to Image that save in Database in VarBinary type

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, c#-4.0

I want to bind an image that save in varbinary type in database in XAML.How I can do that?

for example Picture field in northwind DataBase.

thanks

**EDIT 1:)**

I write this codes for convert Image field (Picture field in Categories table in Northwind DataBase) but every time I get Exception:

```
class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) { return null; }

        var image = (System.Drawing.Image)value;
        var bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;

    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

And :

```
class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is byte[])
        {
            byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();
            return image;
        }
        return null;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

and the exception:

```
Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting byte array from database then no need to convert that to image or bitmap image... 
You can bind Source property of image to byte array.. wpf internally handle the byte array and it converts byte array to image...

**Edit:**

If you still want to convert byte array to Bitmap image here is the method which was tested

```
public BitmapImage ImageFromBytearray(byte[] imageData)
        {

            if (imageData == null)
                return null;
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
            strm.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            strm.Position = 0;
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

I have crated a sample using above method...

**Xaml code:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.ImageFromByteArray"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ImageFromByteArray" Height="300" Width="300" Name="Root">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,ElementName=Root}" Height="300" Width="300"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ImageFromByteArray.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ImageFromByteArray : Window
    {


        public byte[] ByteArray
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte[])GetValue(ByteArrayProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ByteArrayProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ByteArray.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ByteArrayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ByteArray", typeof(byte[]), typeof(ImageFromByteArray));



        public BitmapImage ImageSource
        {
            get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(ImageFromByteArray), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        public ImageFromByteArray()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                ByteArray = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(ByteArray, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();
                ImageSource = ImageFromBytearray(ByteArray);
            }
        }


        public BitmapImage ImageFromBytearray(byte[] imageData)
        {

            if (imageData == null)
                return null;
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
            strm.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            strm.Position = 0;
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved only using a custom converter. Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx) for details on how to implement the "image" part and [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters) for details about creating a converter.

Comment: if I use Value Converter what type I convert Linq.Binary to?

Comment: Binding only works when one (source or destination) property is a dependency property. If you have source property of type Linq.Binary then you need to convert to the destination type.